# How do i strip my strings in my list for my MDDataTable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I want to strip the lists that I use to fill up my MDDataTable Can somebody help me strip the strings This is my python/kivy code.

```
    def build1(self, username):
screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
sql = "SELECT LoggedInUser from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s   "
mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
self.User = mycursor.fetchall()
sql = "SELECT ObjectName from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s     "
mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
self.Object = mycursor.fetchall()
sql = "SELECT Certainty from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects  where LoggedInUser = %s    "
mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
self.Certainty = mycursor.fetchall()
sql = "SELECT TimeOfDetection from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s     "
mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
self.Time = mycursor.fetchall()
sql = "SELECT  idObjecten from ID191774_6itn1project7.DetectedObjects where LoggedInUser = %s     "
mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
self.IDDataTable = mycursor.fetchall()

self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
    size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
    use_pagination=True,
    rows_num=10,
    column_data=[
        ("User", dp(30)),
        ("Object", dp(30)),
        ("Certainty", dp(30)),
        ("Time", dp(30)),

    ],
    row_data=[
        (self.User),
        (self.Object),
        (self.Certainty),
        (self.Time),

    ],
)
return screen
```

And here is the MDDataTable in my running project. [image]

I want to strip the " ('',)". I somebody can help me pls do.

Comment: The values in the row look like tuples, i.e. you need to get value[0] to 'strip off' the ( and the ,). Please edit your code in the question to be a minimal reproducible example with imports/data so anyone can run it (and not using a database, etc.), then maybe you'll get an answer.

Comment: Can you fix your indentations please? And which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (because your code isn't a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guessing is the only way to possibly answer) that your database queries are returning tuples, so that's what you're putting in the rows

So assuming you only get a single value returned from each query, change each place you read the database from e.g.:

```
self.User = mycursor.fetchall()
```

to extract the first value from the tuple e.g.:

```
self.User = mycursor.fetchall()[0]
```

If this doesn't work, rather than saying just 'this doesn't work' please provide some detail of what way it doesn't work, e.g. 'this doesn't work, I get this instead...' and then give the details that aren’t what you want.